# How to get most recent Monday at 12:00am in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Problem: I am organizing objects into groups (weeks) that are classified by their date property to the most recent Monday that has past at 12:00. Given an NSDate, how can I find the most recent Monday at 12:00AM in swift?

Tried: I tried making a for loop and going back until the nearest Monday and then make a new NSDate object and put the time to 12:00AM but for whatever reason I cannot get it to work in swift.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update your question with you have tried and explain what results your get and what results you expect.

Comment: I had a similar problem some time ago. Unfortunately I don't have a complete solution for you but I would use NSDateComponents and NSCalendar http://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/

Comment: beyond what you have tried, please show some sample input and output - what is *"the most recent Monday that has past at 12:00"*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33398047/2303865 does exactly what you want

Comment: thanks I don't know how i missed this