# How do I get the dates for a whole week?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am trying to get the dates for the whole week. I can currently get the current date, but I want to add 6 days to that so I can get a list of the whole week. How would I do that? Any help is appreciated!

```
let now = NSDate()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  print("Now \(now)") //prints current date
}
```

Comment: see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397101/how-to-get-mondays-date-of-the-current-week-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way of doing it:

```
if let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian) {
  var thisWeek = [NSDate]()
  for i in 0...6 {
    if let nextDay = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day , value: i, toDate: NSDate(), options: .MatchStrictly) {
      thisWeek.append(nextDay)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Why won't it work? The first day will be today + 0 days. Next is +1 days...

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah that's just creating the array. I originally manually added the first day and did 1...6 but I simplified it.